# Passing parameter onclick, in a loop

Tags: javascript, loops

Im creating input elements in a loop.
On click, these buttons are supposed to call a certain function with a certain Parameter, based on the Initial creation of the button element.
What in fact does happen is that all Buttons always call the function with Parameter from the LAST button.

```
for (var i = 0; i < planets.length; i++){
  var id = planets[i].id;

  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.type = "button";
  input.className = "worldButton";
  input.value = "Choose this world";
  Input.onclick = function(){
     game.pickWorld(planets, id);
  }
}
```

Each button always seems to pass on the id of planets[planets.length] instead of `planets[i]`.
`console.log(id)` is correct.
It doesnt matter if use `onclick`, `addEventListener` or `jquery.click`.

The whole planets Array however is passed on successfully.

How can i get the Input to correctly pass on the id of that particular Iteration ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to use an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) and create a new closure like

```
for (var i = 0; i < planets.length; i++){
  var id = planets[i].id;

  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.type = "button";
  input.className = "worldButton";
  input.value = "Choose this world";
  
  input.onclick = (function(id, planets){
     return function(){
         game.pickWorld(planets, id);
     }
  })(id,planets);
}
```

What was happening is the variables `planets` and `id` were visible to the callback function and at execution time, were using the last iterated value.

However, with a closure, you effectively created a 'private' variable seen and preserved by **each** callback function.

Answer (score 5):

You need to pass the `id` and `planets` variables in the function like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < planets.length; i++){
  var id = planets[i].id;

  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.type = "button";
  input.className = "worldButton";
  input.value = "Choose this world";
  Input.onclick = (function(pl, id){
     game.pickWorld(pl, id);
  })(planets, id);
}
```

You can read more about IIFE in this [**article**](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/).