# Set onclick method for an element in a loop using local variables without having it activate immediately

Tags: javascript, loops, web, events, callback

I have a for loop in which I'm using a local variable from the loop as a parameter for an onclick event callback. I'm doing it according to what I've read in these posts:

[Passing parameter onclick, in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30476721/passing-parameter-onclick-in-a-loop)

[Javascript - Dynamically assign onclick event in the loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040069/javascript-dynamically-assign-onclick-event-in-the-loop)

However the issue I'm seeing is that the onclick function is only calling once, immediately, and then never again. I found a potential solution in this post:

[Javascript onclick function is called immediately (not when clicked)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29526556/javascript-onclick-function-is-called-immediately-not-when-clicked)

Except that example only seems to work if the onclick function takes no parameters.

SO. How do we both A) set onclick using a local variable in a loop, and B) have it call properly when clicked and not just once the first time?

Here is an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/jq7wbxaz/24/

```
function generateCard() {
  for(var n = 0; n < 5; n++) {
    for(var k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
      var cell = document.createElement("div");
      cell.setAttribute("class", "box");
      cell.setAttribute("id", "r"+n+"c"+k);
      var letter;
      switch(k) {
        case 0:
            letter = "B";
          break;
        case 1:
            letter = "I";
          break;
        case 2:
            letter = "N";
          break;
        case 3:
            letter = "G";
          break;
        case 4:
            letter = "O";
          break;

      }
      cell.innerHTML = letter + n;
      cell.onclick = (function(c) {changeCellColor(c);})(cell);

      document.getElementById("card").appendChild(cell);
    }
  }
} 

function changeCellColor(cell) {
    //var cell = getCell(n, k);
  console.log("Changing color for cell " + cell.id);
    cell.style.backgroundColor = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
}

generateCard();
```

In this fiddle, a bingo card is being generated. The desired behavior is for each box of the card to have an onclick function that changes that boxes color. Instead, they all are a random color at start and onclick doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to reference `this` in the function you call when the cell is clicked. It refers to the cell's element.

So, your onclick function will become this:

`cell.onclick = function() { changeCellColor(this) };`

[More examples here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)

Comment: That did it. Thank you!

Comment: No worries! I always forget how function binding is meant to work. So many quirks!